# Equivalence relation between two CFG's

Tags: automata, context-free, equality

In our course: Automata and Computation there is a definition about Context-Free Grammars which states:

"Two CFG's $CFG_{1}$ and $CFG_{2}$ are equivalent if $L_{CFG_{1}} = L_{CFG_{2}}$ where $L_{CFG_{i}}$ is the language that is derived by $CFG_{i}$".

Below the definition, it is stated that this defines an equivalence relation of the CFG's, but I don't see how I could prove this. I know that I should prove the 3 properties of an equivalence relation being:

-Reflexive
-Symmetric
-Transitive

But how can I do this for the particular problem?

Comment: Did you ever prove that a relation is an equivalence relation? If you didn't, check how it's proved in other cases (see some examples of equivalence relations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Equivalence_relations)), this one is the same.

Comment: Yes I did, but I don't see how I can translate proving that a relation is an equivalence relation to proving that this is also the case for CFG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the set of all context-free grammars and let $\rho \subseteq \mathcal{G}^2$ denote the binary relation "being equivalent to".

Let $G$ be a CFG grammar. Clearly it holds that $G \rho G$ since $L_G=L_G$. Therefore $\rho$ is reflexive.

Let $G$ and $G'$ be CFG grammars such that $G \rho G'$. By definition of $\rho$ we have $L_{G} = L_{G'}$ and since set-equality is symmetric we also have $L_{G'} = L_{G}$. This shows that $G' \rho G$ and hence $\rho$ is symmetric.

Let $G$, $G'$ and $G''$ be CFG grammars such that $G \rho G'$ and $G' \rho G''$. By definition of $\rho$, we have $L_G = L_{G'}$ and $L_{G'} = L_{G''}$ and by transitivity of set-equality we have $L_G =  L_{G''}$ showing that $G \rho G''$ and that $\rho$ is transitive.

Comment: So basically if something like this is asked, it's best to define a relation like "being equivalent to" and proving that that is an equivalence relation?

Comment: The relation was already defined in the question. I just named it with a symbol ($\rho$) for brevity.

Comment: Oh now I see where I missed. Looks like I just didn't pay enough attention to the question.

Comment: @Nathaniel thanks for the edit!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

$G_1$ and $G_2$ are equivalent if and only if $L_{G_1} = L_{G_2}$.

Since the relation $=$ is an equivalence relation over languages, so is the equivalence between grammars.